# How do I check the apache config for validity in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: apache, rhel

My operating system is Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.  This isn't working...

```
# httpd -t
bash: httpd: command not found
```

In case it helps, this is the command I run to restart apache on this box...

```
# systemctl restart httpd24-httpd
```

But this doesn't work...

```
# httpd24-httpd -t
bash: httpd24-httpd: command not found
```

This doesn't work either...

```
# apachectl -t
bash: apachetl: command not found
```

Nor does this work...

```
# apachectl configtest
bash: apachetl: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is a couple months old but ended up here.  I ran into the same issue initially, hence why I am here.  I found that the location for the new httpd24-httpd wasn't in my env path to execute. While I could added it there, I found the command location and was able to execute.

How I found the command:

```
sudo find / -name apachectl
```

The output of the command:

/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/apachectl

Executed the command:

```
sudo /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

Turns out I have to fix my configuration.

httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 40 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_http2.so into server: libnghttp2-httpd24.so.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Interesting that this came up for me, as I've not done anything with the configuration in this regard.

Here's the version I am running.

```
sudo /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/apachectl -v
```

Server version: Apache/2.4.34 (Red Hat)
Server built:   Mar 17 2020 09:34:59

All the best!

Found something more for this as well from an old bug submitted to Redhat

[Bug 1329639](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1329639)

Comment 10

```
scl enable httpd24 -- /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/apachectl configtest
```